# Arrow keys change full-screen background image

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I’m implementing a [Wordpress theme](http://www.gallyapp.com/tf_themes/?theme=Pluto) for a client, and just discovered that when you press one of the arrow keys (repeatedly) to scroll the page content (rather than using the mouse), it causes the theme's full-screen background images to rotate as well. The same thing happens when you press any of the other directional keys repeatedly. Is there any way to disable this functionality/feature?

Here's the theme: http://www.gallyapp.com/tf_themes/?theme=Pluto

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the source code for the page there is a script being used for those changes called supersized.

On line 216 there is a variable being set

```
keyboard_nav            :   1,      //Keyboard navigation on/off
```

Change this 1 to a 0 and it should be disabled. eg:

```
keyboard_nav            :   0,      //Keyboard navigation on/off
```

I'm personally not familiar with the theme but this javascript will be in one of the headers of theme normally found in:

```
wp-content/themes/THEME_NAME/header.php
```